# Stuck on "Instance is being verified"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cloud, cloud-computing

I've created instance groups of min. 2-instances by using Google Cloud. When I hover over the state of the instance group it says **it is transforming** while the instances are being verified. Please help,

[image: Detailed view]

Answer (score 0):

As I can see at the screenshot **your VM instances are unhealthy**, because of that  MIG autohealing recreates unhealthy VMs using the original instance template and, as a result, your MIG is in transforming state. Please have a look at the documentation [Setting up health checking and autohealing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/autohealing-instances-in-migs) section [Autohealing behavior](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/autohealing-instances-in-migs#autohealing_behavior) to find more details.

**To solve this issue**:

1. You should check [GCP Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) rules to be sure that you allowed connections to your MIG instances from subnets `35.191.0.0/16` and `130.211.0.0/22` to ports you configured at your health-check. More details you can find at the documentation [Example health check set up](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/autohealing-instances-in-migs#setting_up_an_autohealing_policy).
2. SSH into VM instances and check that NGINX web server is running and responses with HTTP status is 200 (OK). It's required for health-check probe to be considered as successful. You can do it with `curl` command reaching same path you configured at your health-check at the local IP.

Comment: Hello @studentd5d8a5ed and welcome to ServerFault! Please remember to [react to answers for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). 
That way we know if the answers were helpful and other community members could also benefit from them. Try to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that is the final solution for your issue, upvote answers that are helpful and comment on those which could be improved or require additional attention. Enjoy your stay!